# Why it doesn't return any value?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MarkCalculator {

    public static int[] exam_grade = new int[6];
    public static int[] coursework_grade = new int[6];
    public static int[] coursework_weight = new int[2];
    public static int[] module_points = new int[6];
    public static String[] module_grade = new String[20];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){

            System.out.printf(i+". Modelue"+" Enter grade of exam:");
            exam_grade[i]=input.nextInt();

            System.out.printf(i+". Modelue"+" Enter grade of coursework:");
            coursework_grade[i]=input.nextInt(); 
        }

        for(int i = 0 ;i < 3; i++){
            System.out.println(exam_grade[i]+" "+coursework_grade[i]); 
        }

        computeMark(module_points, coursework_grade, exam_grade);

        for(int i = 0 ;i < 3; i++){
            System.out.println(module_points[i]); 
        }

        input.close();
    }

    public static int[] computeMark (int coursework_grade[], int exam_grade[], int             module_points[]){

        coursework_weight[0]= 50;
        coursework_weight[1]= 50;

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

            if (coursework_grade[i] < 35 || exam_grade[i] < 35){
                module_points[i]=((coursework_grade[i]*coursework_weight[0] +     (exam_grade[i]*(100-coursework_weight[1])))/100);
            }
        }

        return module_points;

    }

}
```

I wonder why it doesn't return any value. The function module_points worked few days ago and now I just can't find any error there. The output is all the time 0 only. Anyone can help pls? Thank you.I bet it's just something simple but really stuck at this point. What i need to do is: based on input (coursework_grade and exam_grade) count the module_points (formula is given), store these values in the array and return this array to the main method where is this array showed. Thanks for help guys.

Comment: There is no function `module_points`

Comment: What do you see when you step through your code in your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function `computeMark()` without storing the returned result.

Change:

```
computeMark(module_points, coursework_grade, exam_grade);
```

To: [edited]

```
module_points = computeMark(coursework_grade, exam_grade, module_points);
```

Comment: this works but for some reason it return half of the real value..when the input from exam_grade and coursework_grade is 100 it should return 100 as well...but it return only 50...any idea? I can't edit code which I posted here so just ignore that condition if exam_grade or coursework_grade is under 35...just want count module_points

Comment: The order of variables that are passed to the function mismatch the variables that function asks for.

Use: `module_points = computeMark(coursework_grade, exam_grade, module_points);`

Comment: it works now...I knew it will be something stupid and easy..thanks for help

Comment: Are u there mate? I'd like to ask you one more thing if I can

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got `0` with divide by `100`. Declare `module_points[]` as `double[]` to get the fraction value.

Answer (score 0):

see the part:

```
    if (coursework_grade[i] < 35 || exam_grade[i] < 35)
    {
      module_points[i]= ......
    }
```

This means all your inputs must be >= 35  Otherwise no association of module_point array elements will occur.

Comment: I cannot edit code which I pasted here...I deleted this condition but it returns wrong values...when I enter 100 from coursework_grade and exam_grade as well it return only 50 but it should return 100